# Getting Apple - Logic X to recognize outputs in mono as opposed to stereo pairs

Tags: software, daw, logic-pro

So I'm pretty new to Mac and Logic X. I'm using a Focusrite Sapphire 40 with this setup and my goal is to have single audio track assigned to a single audio output output in mono.  However, Logic will only recognize each output as a stereo pair.  I am forced to assign each track to a pair, and if I want mono I have to hard pan the audio track.  Just wondering if there's some trick to this, or if I'm forced to do the panning method to get a single track on a single mono output.  Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to have it mono?  Usually a mono track will come out of both channels but it sounds more like you are trying to get the main output to be mono, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono tracks can be routed to one single output. Go to the track's output routing options and you'll find mono options (you can do this from the inspector or from the mixer).

[image: Output options]

Non-mono tracks can't be routed to mono outputs.

The Sapphire series has its own mixer software that you might need to configure too. If you are not seeing mono routing options for mono tracks the issue might be with the sapphire mixer software.

I remember having to tweak something in that sapphire mixer software every time I work with a Sapphire interface. It has its own routing system, so you might need to register the outputs as selectable for mono routing or something like that.